# Create user in Kibana that maintains same dashboards configuration than admin

Tags: kibana

Dear Stackoverflow community,

Working with Opendistro ELK, I made several configs for index patterns, dashboards, etc. even I modified the "/home" button to link to a main dashboard with navigation buttons.
But now I need to add more users and cannot find the way to keep the configuration accessible for new created users by default.

Any idea about it?
Thanks

7.8.0

Comment: even creating a new user, I cannot see any dashboards. And I loaded them using the "setup dashboards" for every agent... Really I didn't expected to get stacked at this...

Comment: Coudl be a role issue? Form the doc it says that the after you create the user it can't do much and you need to assign more roles to it https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-started-roles.html

Comment: Thanks for the attention Marco, tomorrow I will stay working on this, please keep an eye on this topic. I appreciate any support. It seems i created the dashboards using "private" tenant, and I cannot find the way to give access to that dashboards to other users.. Also I was trying to export only dashboards and re-import to othe rusers but it seems the permissions are exported too...